# why is my image getting covered?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I started watching a youtube video series on learning pygame by sentdex.
I have been following all his steps and i got to the point where i had a car(the image) and it was on a white screen. But, when i put in the functions to be able to move the car. Next time i ran it I could not see my car. I noticed that I could see it for a split second when i closed the screen.I have tried searching this question every way that i could think of. It is probably a small stupid mistake on    my part. Thank you in advance
    import pygame

```
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')

def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))


x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.6)

x_change = 0

crashed = False

while not crashed:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    crashed = True

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        x_change = -5
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_change = 5

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_change = 0

x += x_change             

gameDisplay.fill(white)           
car(x,y)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Please indent your code example correctly, since your error could be a result of incorrect indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is messed up. Everything from `for event in pygame.event.get():` to `clock.tick(60)` should be indented to show that it fits inside the `while not crashed:` loop. Also, `crashed = True` should be indented to show that it is inside the `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` statement. In addition, the `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.KEYUP` comparisons should be inside your `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop. Finally, you can improve speed by changing some of the `if`s to `elif`s. This is the corrected version of the last section of your code:

```
while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change             

    gameDisplay.fill(white)           
    car(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was getting so frustrated